# Why my conditional and my input is not read inside my loop in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to make a simple code in python but i dont know why in the while loop var1 and var2 is no reading, what is wrong in this code?

```
    var1 = 1
    var2 = 1
    while True:
      var1=int(input('''
                Hola!, responda utilizando lo que esta dentro del parentesis.
                si usted es:
                Adulto (1)
                Nino (0)
                '''))
      print(var1)
      if var1 == 0:
        print('Perfecto eres un nino')
      elif var1 ==1:
        'Cuentanos tu estado acutal:'
      else:
        'Elige un numero que sea 1 o 0'
        continue
      break
    
    while var1 == 1:
      var2 = int(input('''
                      Casado (1)
                      Soltero (0)
                      '''))
      if var2 != 1 or var2 != 0:
        print('Como en la anterior pregunta, porfavor contesta con 0 o 1')
        continue
      break
    
    
    if var2 ==1:
      print('Ustes es un adulto y espero que muy felizmente casado')
    else:
      print('Ustes es un adulto y soltero')
```

Comment: `if var2 != 1 or var2 != 0:` => `if var2 != 1 and var2 != 0:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the second, while loop, because you continue the while loop when the var2 is not 1 or not 0. That means if var2 is 1 it is not 0 and because of that the while loop continues. If you change this part to the following it should work.

```
    if var2 not in (1, 0):
        print('Como en la anterior pregunta, porfavor contesta con 0 o 1')
        continue
```

Comment: Thank you, i understand the problem and the logic,  i dont know how i cant get it jaja